# Is there some sort of open source repository of translated strings stored in .mo, or similar formats?

Tags: localization, internationalization, gettext

Just curious, I reckon I'll have to hire a translator to do my .mo files manually but would be great if there was some sort of resource for this.

Sorry if this question doesn't belong or isn't a "real" question, but it is related to web application localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try one of next resources:

- [Rosetta](https://launchpad.net/) - Ubuntu translation platform
- [OpenOffice.org Localization Project](http://l10n.openoffice.org/)
- [Google Translation](http://translate.google.com/) - The quality is better than you may think and is already using existing open source translations.